# Suddenly lost ability to connect to internet

Tags: networking, internet

I've been using Ubuntu 22.04 without an issue for over a year. Yesterday it closed normally, today it opened normally, but server not found is what I get when I try to connect to the internet. I'm using Firefox. Computer, HP with Intel i5-10400T CPU tells it is connected to the internet. I checked the router, restarted  the router, restarted the computer, after wifi connected with a cable, but there is still no internet connection.

Comment: Maybe there's an issue with your internet service provider. What happens when you run a live session from an Ubuntu USB?